# How to merge branches in git without actually merging?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-merge

I want to merge two branches, but all I want to do is to overwrite the file in master wherever it has changed.

I used to do this by checking out files one by one from the other branch, but that way I will lose the history once I delete the branch.

Any solution to that? Thanks!

Comment: You want to modify the overwrite the files in master, with the version that are in the branch, and not lose the history. Why don't you want to merge?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could do:

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs my_branch
```

That is almost what you asked for. The difference is that the result will be a merge of both branch, but in case of conflicts, the version of `my_branch` is chosen to resolve the conflict.